# Where is the storage of the array (e.g. a(10000)) defined in module in Fortran 90 ? Is it put in the stack?

Tags: arrays, fortran, heap-memory, stack-overflow, stack-memory

I am facing problems of stack overflow for my Fortran 90 program. I put all the parameters in module, and i got segment fault when running big examples, which makes me confused TAT. I have written a small program to verify my assumption of where the problem might be. I got some interesting phenomenon, and want to ask what is the principle of them.

1. I put an extremely large array in a module (etc. `REAL a(10000000)`). When I use it in the subroutine, there won't be segment fault. Thus I am wondering where the storage of the array is?
2. I allocate an extremely large array (etc. `allocate(a(10000000))`) in a subroutine `A`, and transmit it into another subroutine `B`. In B, I define it as `a(10000000)`, and there won't be segment fault. Thus I am wondering what is transmitted between two subroutine of an allocatable array?
3. For my own complicated program, I have checked several times that I allocate every arrays in module, but the  segment fault is still happened when example is getting large. I just want to know if there is something I'm missing which will influence the usage of stack.

Now, I have no idea where to check TAT, so is there anybody can give me some insight of debugging the segment fault with stack overflow? I will appreciate so much for that!

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is just one very old standard revision.  Please be aware that these details are not controlled by the standard. You should mention tour compiler version and the compiler flags you are using because flags can change this behaviour.

Comment: You should normally ask one question per post. Regarding point 3, you **must** show your code. See [mcve] and [ask]. We cannot tell you why some code is crashing without seeing the code.

Comment: There is a significant lack of information.  What operating system?  What restrictions does your operating system place on the stack?  What compiler and compiler options?

Comment: Even more basic why do you think your segmentation fault is caused by a stackoverflow? There can be many other reasons. You have compiled and run with all run time checking on (-fcheck=all for gfortran) and seen if that tells you anything, haven't you? And just to reiterate Vladimir, the Fortran standard says nothing about stacks, *if* the problem is to do with a stack we can not answer without knowing details about your implementation.

Comment: Intel Fortran has the option for placing arrays in the heap when bigger than a specified size. Does this imply that smaller arrays are always on the stack? I don't know.

Comment: What is 'TAT'? Don't overdo the TLAs here please.

Comment: @steve Thank you for your advise! I had solved this problem by using the -check flag and found the array where stack overflow. Next time I will mention detailed compiler information when asking question.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Thank you for your advise! I had solved this problem by using the -check flag and found the array where stack overflow. Next time I will learn more about how to describe a bug before asking question. It was the first time I tried ask question here, thus I appreciate your patience for telling me these standard rules.

Comment: @IanBush I had solved this problem by following your advise to use the -check flag and found the array where stack overflow. Thank you very much!  Actually I want some tips to check my codes and I should learn more in the future. Also next time I will learn more about how to describe a bug before asking question.

Comment: @user207421 I'm sorry and that was just a emoji. I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to replicate the problem with Intel Fortran (oneAPI HPC kit, `ifort`). To mitigate the problem I setup heap arrays when over 1000 kb in size.

[image: fig1]

The following test code

```
program Console2
use LU_MODULE
    
integer, parameter :: n = 359
real(wp) :: A(n,n), LU(n,n), b(n), x(n), delta
integer :: indx(n), d, ierr

call RANDOM_SEED()
call RANDOM_NUMBER(A)
call RANDOM_NUMBER(b)

A = 3*(A + eye(n))   ! Line 18, where error occus
print *, 'n=', n, ' mem=', sizeof(A)/1024, 'kb'

...
```

Fails when `n>=359` without this setting.

```
forrtl: severe (170): Program Exception - stack overflow
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
FortranConsole2.e  00007FF7F363A727  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
FortranConsole2.e  00007FF7F363509A  MAIN__                     18  program.f90
FortranConsole2.e  00007FF7F3637E6E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
FortranConsole2.e  00007FF7F363AA59  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
FortranConsole2.e  00007FF7F363A97E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
FortranConsole2.e  00007FF7F363A83E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
FortranConsole2.e  00007FF7F363AACE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       00007FFC336A7034  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          00007FFC33B42651  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

but with the setting enabled I get the expected output

```
 n=         359  mem=                  1006 kb
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I had solved this problem by using the -check flag and found the array where stack overflow.
However, your tips is very useful because it can mitigate some stack-overflow problems! I use Intel Fortran compiler too but in linux.  Do you know how to change this option without visual studio IDE ?

Comment: @HuiwenZhang try option [`-heap-arrays 1000`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/advanced-optimization-options/heap-arrays.html)